# Isomorphism class of $\mathbf{U}(p^n)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Note that $\mathbf{U}(k)$ is the unitary group.
i.e. $\mathbf{U}(k)=\{x<k | \gcd(x,k)=1\}$
We need to find the isomorphism class of $\mathbf{U}(p^n)$ where  $p$ is an odd prime.

The isomorphism class is 
$\mathbf{Z}/\left<p^n - p^{n-1}\right>$.

I am not able to prove it.

I started with $|\mathbf{U}(p^n)|$ which is the Euler's phi function. Which turns out to be $p^n-p^{n-1}$.

Now i want to show that $\mathbf{U}(p^n)$ is cyclic, which i have no clue how to!

Please help me out!

Comment: Notice $U(8) = \{1,3,5,7\}$ is not cyclic. It is elementary abelian with $1^2=3^2=5^2=7^2$.

Comment: I'll just edit the question. p>2. Sorry

Comment: Is $U(n)$ the unitary group of matrices? Or the invertible elements modulo $n$?

Comment: Invertible elements modulo n.

Comment: @SwapnilTri: *Please* edit your question to make it legible: neither of your first two lines form complete sentences

Answer (score 2):

It is called the theorem on existence of primitive root and the proof is not very easy. If you already know the existence of primitive roots modulo $p$ then here is a hint for induction proof:

if $\xi$ is primitive modulo $p^{n-1}$ then if $\xi$ is not primitive modulo $p^{n}$ then $\xi+p^{n-1}$ is.  Just because $(\xi +p^{n-1})^k=\xi^{k}+kp^{n-1}$.

Also here is wiki page:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what is the order of the element $1 + p$?

Comment: When $n=1$ you have $1+p=1$ which cannot be a generator ;)

Comment: @N.S.: True. This works for $n > 1$ (which should be a case in the question statement)

Comment: No, It does not work for $n>1$ because, for $n=2$ $(1+p)^{p}=1$...

Comment: @user68061: This is not a full hint: $1+p$ is not a generator of the full group of units, only of the Sylow-$p$ subgroup. Having this, it suffices to find an element of order $p - 1$...

Comment: Oh, sorry, you are right)

Comment: @user68061: I probably should have made this clearer upfront. You are correct though in that this problem is actually not very easy

Comment: I just learned this fact way before I studied any group theory or knew the term "Sylow subgroup''. So I just didn't thought about proving it like this. For $\mathbb{F}_p$ one can use standart ``finite subgroup of a field'' argument and then proceed by induction. This is not easier then your argument just more direct